# A non-dystopian novel with a city/country/world scale AI as a protagonist or main character

Tags: story-identification

I vaguely remember reading a sci-fi novel (though, it could have been a novelette, maybe even a longer short story) that had a city/country/empire sized AI (basically a government replacement), that showed this AI in a positive (non-dystopian) light? It might have been a swarm-like / extra-terrestrial government or society with shared intelligence, and not a traditional AI.

Ann Leckie had something similar going with Ancillary Justice and her global AI construct playing a prominent role in the novels, but it was something that went deeper in how such an AI would operate as a city/country/empire manager and solve standard empire / sovereign dilemmas much more effectively than humans / separate beings, instead of the standard trope of building a Big Brother type of society.

More details about the plot: there was a war or conflict with an alternative empire and AI would manipulate / fix the issues but making it with a light touch, so that people would think they are still in control. The AI is sort of all-calculating, at a level that humans could never achieve and is always right and the twist is that everything was planned.

Comment: EPICAC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPICAC_(short_story) There is this but I think that is not it.

Comment: Also, this is another example of such computer: Multivac https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivac

Comment: There's the *Eschaton* books by Charles Stross but they're novels, except the short story "Bear Trap" set in that same universe, the Eschaton A.I.s tend to be fairly benevolent.

Comment: Also check the literature sections of these links "Master Computer" and "The computer is your friend" on tvtropes:  https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MasterComputer and  https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheComputerIsYourFriend . One of the examples is "Maneki Neko" by Bruce Sterling.

Comment: Nobody's mentioned the *Culture* universe?!

Comment: "The Evitable Conflict" by Asimov had Earth divided into 4 regions, each run by a Machine.

Comment: Any details about the actual plot?

Comment: I'm not posting an answer yet, since there are obviously far too many possibilities, but others to consider include Monitor from *The World and Thorinn* (Knight), ARDNEH from *The Empire of the East* (Saberhagen) and Spartacus from *The Two Faces of Tomorrow* (Hogan).  And those are just the _long form_, _older_ works that might fit.

Comment: This is pretty broad. the Bobiverse could almost fit, if you're only recalling the parts where the humans show up and the Bobs take care of them.

Comment: I'm reminded of the short story "State Machine" by Yudhanjaya Wijeratne:  https://slate.com/technology/2020/09/state-machine-yudhanjaya-wijeratne.html

Comment: When did you read this (approximately)?  If it's long enough ago some of the more recent possibilities can be discarded on that basis.

Comment: I think it was quite modern, 10-15 years tops, I believe

Comment: @DavidW It _really_ sounds like The Culture, doesn't it?

Answer (score 8):

First possibility: the computer known as Mycroft Holmes (“Mike”), Adam Selene, etc in Robert A Heinlein’s *The Moon is a Harsh Mistress*.

A more detailed description can be found here:

https://annex.fandom.com/wiki/Mycroft_Holmes_(computer)

Here’s an excerpt.

“In Robert A. Heinlein's novel The Moon Is a Harsh Mistress (1966), the character Mycroft Holmes is a self-aware computer system entrusted with running the life-support systems, communications, payroll and many other things, in a penal colony underground in the Moon or "Luna".[1] Mycroft eventually sides with characters inciting a revolution to free Luna, and is instrumental in their victory against the Lunar Authority on Earth.”

Comment: My first thought too.  You beat me to it though.

Comment: (not a policy, but my idea of good practice) If you're able to answer a [tag:story-identification] question with more than one answer it's not clear enough and should be closed first. I don't think that you've done is necessarily wrong, but it feels like a red flag about the question.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage I'd disagree, because sometimes even a good description can have multiple potential matches and only the asker can ever truly know which answer is the correct one.  Basically, your self-policy should result in story-identification questions with either only one answer and no comments (because they are 100% identifiable with no clarification needed), or no answers or comment at all (because answerers cant be 100% sure they are the right answer, which means the question is not clear enough...).

Comment: @moo there is a middle ground. My point was the answerer here has given multiple answers. They can't all be correct.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage is that any different to those answers coming from different people?

Comment: @moi yes, because you should be confident in your answer when you post it. If you are posting multiple 'attempts' that's not the case. The principle is to stop somebody post a large number as like a scatter gun approach.

Comment: I don't think it was that old, the book was relatively modern

Answer (score 4):

Reminds me a bit of "Achilles' Choice" by Larry Niven. Although the main plot was about the MC's choice as to whether to accept the physiological enhancements necessary to be competitive in the Olympics, it did cover the ideas of a "near perfect" government managed by AIs. I recall that there was still one human at the centre of things and various discussions of the nature of AI based government and how much of that could be effectively overseen or controlled by a single individual - which seems relevant to the second paragraph of the question. The Goodreads synopsis/blurb-copy has these points:

> The rulers of the 21st century had created a nearly perfect system of government: A world free from war, disease, and want, dominated by global corporations, managed by omniscient artificial intelligences.

> ... connection to the Link, the global information network that sustained the world.

> Few had ever dared to question the workings of the system. None who had questioned survived.

> Pitting faith and raw courage against awesome technological might, one woman risked her life to defy the godlike power of Earth’s masters

It is also quite short for a novel so that matches the "could be novelette" !

[GoodReads - Achilles Choice](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/850597.Achilles_Choice)

Update: The OP has added some more details to the question which pretty much rule out this answer. In this novel there are no external societies or AIs, all the conflict is within the global earth based society.

Answer (score 2):

Supreme, the computer which effectively runs a galaxy-wide government in [*Watchers of the Dark*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?4563) by Lloyd Biggle Jr, and in later novels in the "Jan Darzek" series.

Matching points:

- Supreme is literally world-size: its structure is the capital planet.
- Supreme controls pretty much all governmental functions, plus the universal banking system used to make all payment for goods and services.
- Supreme is generally shown positivly, althoguh in some cases it misunderstands thinjgs, and in other cases its individual advisors misunderstand its warnings.

Neutral points

- *Watchers of the Dark* is a novel, albeit a short one by current standards.

Possibly non-matching points

- *Watchers of the Dark*  was published in 1966, and the most recent paper edition shown by the ISFDB is 1975, there is a 2013 ebook edition.
- The twist that "everything comes out as planned" does not seem to fit this novel, it comes closer to fitting [*This Darkening Universe*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?4564) (1975) in the same series by the same author.
- The central role of the protagonist, Jam Darzek (born on Earth) is not mentioned by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

The Oversoul in Orson Scott Card's Homecoming Saga.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homecoming_Saga):

> On Harmony, the colonists established the Oversoul – an artificial intelligence, monitoring the planet with a small army of satellites. It also influences the actions of humans.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! However, this is a bit brief for a proper answer -- please [edit] your answer to explain why you think this is the answer (e.g. explain which details match).